# Reindex in Pandas is not accepting axis argument?

Tags: python, pandas, reindex

I am running the examples in the pandas documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)
and I got an unexpected exception:

```
index = ['Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'IE10', 'Konqueror']
df = pd.DataFrame({
      'http_status': [200,200,404,404,301],
      'response_time': [0.04, 0.02, 0.07, 0.08, 1.0]},
       index=index)

df.reindex(['http_status', 'user_agent'], axis="columns")
TypeError: reindex() got an unexpected keyword argument "axis"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [pandas under 0.21.0 problem](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#rename-reindex-now-also-accept-axis-keyword), so use general solution:

```
df = df.reindex(columns=['http_status', 'user_agent'])
```

Comment: Should I update my pandas module and if yes how?  I have installed it through Anaconda 3

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Under windows in `cmd` use `conda update pandas`

Comment: Thank you.  I upgraded the Pandas but now I can not import pandas_datareader.  I get the exception: "ImportError: cannot import name 'is_list_like'".  Could you look at my post and possibly reply? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50796476/how-to-import-pandas-datareader-with-latest-version-of-pandas

Comment: @user8270077 - Unfortunately I have no experience with it :(